# Snowflake won't recognize numeric values as such

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, sqlalchemy, snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am using SQL alchemy to load a pandas dataframe into snowflake. Pandas offers the to_sql method to easily do this. Here is my call:

```
df = **a pandas dataframe**
name = **a name for the table**
con = **a snowflake connection**

df.to_sql(name = table,
          con = con,
          if_exists = 'replace',
          index = False)
```

this yields the following error

```
100038 (22018): Numeric value '326.36' is not recognized
```

At first I thought maybe this had something to do with the decimal point, so I also tried hardcoding the dtype parameter in the to_sql method to float instead of using the default, but that yields the same result.

I think this is some issue with snowflake, but I can't figure out what. Has anyone seen this before?

Comment: Adding a reddit thread for further context - I see it's pretty hard to reproduce https://www.reddit.com/r/snowflake/comments/jxv85e/why_doesnt_snowflake_recognize_this_number/

Comment: Can you share the dtypes of the frame, as well as the table DDL that you are loading to?  You might need to make sure the df is set with the float before the to_sql method, since the table definition is created from the df definition, and a 'replace' is recreating your table.  You may also want to test creating the table ahead of time and changing the if_exists to append just as a test.

Comment: also, are you on the latest snowflake drivers for python and sqlalchemy?

Comment: @MikeWalton To your first point, the dataframe column is a float64 and the target field in snowflake is FLOAT so afaik they should be compatible. To your second point, I don't think its a drivers issue because I can reproduce the problem from within the snowflake UI. If I try to insert values to the dataframe, sometimes it throw the error I described and sometimes it doesn't, seemingly dependent on how many values I am trying to insert at a time. However even if I were reaching some sort of sql character or row limit, that wouldn't affect the datatype of the data I am inserting

Comment: I was thinking this was specifically a dataframe issue.  Are you saying that a simple insert statement in Snowflake UI has this issue?  Can you post an example of that?

Comment: Yeah, i'm 99% sure its something to do with snowflake and not sqlalchemy, pandas etc. I haven't figured out the minimum necessary conditions to reproduce yet.

Comment: If you can reproduce the error with the Snowflake UI, please note the query id with the error - and share with support.